# Show Image Banner between the date

Tags: magento2, collection, banner

I am displaying my banner on the page, it is displaying correct.

I want to show the Banner between the dates from the "`display_from`" to "`display_to`".

I am getting my all date in this code, above date is also getting.

I want to show the banner between the dates that are getting in the template:

My code:

```
/** @var \Vendor\BannerSlider\Model\Banner[] $bannerCollection */
$bannerCollection = $block->getBannerCollection();
//var_dump($bannerCollection);
?>
<div class="bf-banner-sliders-block">
    <div data-role="loader" class="loading-mask">
        <div class="loader">
            <img src="<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $block->getViewFileUrl('images/loader-1.gif'); ?>"
                 alt="<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ __('Loading...') ?>">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="bf-banner-sliders no-display" id="bf-banner-sliders" data-block="bf-banner-sliders">

        <?php
      if





        foreach ($bannerCollection as $banner) :?>
            <div class="banner-slider slick-slider">
                <div class="banner-image">
                    <a href="<?= $banner->getBannerUrl()?: 'javascript:void(0);'?>">
                        <picture>
                            <!--[if IE 9]><video style="display: none;"><![endif]-->
                            <?php if ($imageDesktopUrl = $banner->getImageDesktopUrl()) :?>
                                <source srcset="<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $imageDesktopUrl;?>" media="(min-width: 1024px)">
                            <?php endif; ?>
                            <?php if ($imageTabletUrl = $banner->getImageTabletUrl()) :?>
                                <source srcset="<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $imageTabletUrl;?>" media="(min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 1023px)">
                            <?php endif; ?>
                            <?php if ($imageMobileUrl = $banner->getImageMobileUrl()) :?>
                                <source srcset="<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $imageMobileUrl;?>" media="(max-width: 767px)">
                            <?php endif; ?>
                            <!--[if IE 9]></video><![endif]-->
                            <img data-lazy="<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $imageDesktopUrl;?>" srcset="<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $imageDesktopUrl;?>" alt="<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $banner->getTitle();?>">
                        </picture>
                    </a>
                </div>
                <div class="banner-content <?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $block->escapeHtml($banner->getAlignText()) ?>">
                    <h2 class="banner-title"><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $block->escapeHtml($banner->getTitle()) ?></h2>
                    <?php if ($banner->getDescription()) :?>
                        <div class="banner-inner <?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $block->escapeHtml($banner->getAlignText()) ?>">
                            <span class="banner-caption"><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $banner->getDescription()?></span>
                        </div>
                    <?php endif;?>
                    <?php if ($banner->hasButton()) :?>
                        <?php $buttonUrl  = $banner->getButtonUrl();?>
                        <?php $buttonText = $banner->getButtonText() ?: __('Shop Now');?>
                        <div class="banner-button">
                            <a href="<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $buttonUrl ?: 'javascript:void(0);'?>"
                               title="<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $buttonText?>">
                                <span><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $buttonText?></span>
                            </a>
                        </div>
                    <?php endif;?>
                </div>
            </div>
        <?php endforeach;?>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Just put if condition before foreach loop like `If (current_date >= display_from && current_date <= display_to)`

Comment: it will works fine?

Comment: Can you please include the condition, where you want to place the your condition in the phtml template?

Comment: @RanaZain Could you demonstrate the code used to retrieve the display_from and display_to dates?

Comment: Sorry I can't understand what are you saying, can you please provide more details, I think you want to display the dates from the configurations into the templates frontend